Why code below doesn't compile and what can we do to make it compile in the end?
My code:
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val)
{
    f(val);
}

int main()
{
    auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with(print, 42);
}

The error I get:

Error (active)    E0304   no instance of function template "call_with"
matches the argument list

Why do we even need std::function if it can't automatically convert from lambdas? Or there is some special behaviour due to templates?

If you get build errors, then [edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log. And add a comment in the code where you get the error.

And you don't need the std::function. Do e.g. template<typename F, typename T> void call_with(F function, T const& value) { function(value); }. This is basically what the standard library itself is doing to handle callable objects.

A lambda is not a std::function (although it can be converted to one), and therefore automatic type deduction cannot work. You can use: call_with<int>(print, 42);.

call_with(std::function{print}, 42); will work too.

Re: "Why do we even need std::function"? You don't. std::function is vastly overused (read: abused). It's not a fancy version of a function pointer. It does argument type conversions and return type conversion, things which a function pointer can't do. If you don't need them you don't need std::function.

The type for your template cannot be automatically deduced in this line:
call_with(print, 42);

Because a lambda is not a std::function (although it can be converted to one).
You can solve it by specifying the template argument explicitly:
call_with<int>(print, 42);

Live demo 1
Alternatively as suggested in the comment you can avoid using std::function in your template and use another generic parameter that can be replaced with any callable:
template<typename F, typename T> 
void call_with(F f, T const& value) 
{ 
    f(value); 
}

And then use it as you attempted:
call_with(print, 42);

Live demo 2

Third option, std::type_identity_t<std::function<...>> as the first parameter to inhibit deduction from it. But your second option is better than this.

try this:
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val)
{
    f(val);
}
int main()
{
    auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with<decltype(print), int>(print, 42);
}


This doesn't work

call_with() takes 1 template argument, but you are passing in 2 instead. You probably meant to write template <typename F, typename T> void call_with(F f, T val), in which case you don't need to pass the template arguments explicitly since argument type deduction will work as expected in that case.
